# AcceptChanges on DataTable reverts cell styles

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView with a BindingSource as it's data source and a DataTable as BindingSource's data source.
When I load data and my grid, I set up style on some cells by calling:

```
grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

My BindingSource has some logic on CurrentChanged event. When the current row changes at the end of this logic I call AcceptChanges on my DataTable. Unfortunately this causes cell style of this row's cells beeing reverted to the original state.

How to force grid not to revert cell styles on DataTable.AcceptChanges?
Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the color of cell depend on some attributes or columns of the datatable bound?

I guess when you call AcceptChanges it causes the DataGridView to redraw as its underlying datasource has changed.

What I'd try is using `RowDataBound` or `CellFormatting` event and change the color (of the column in corresponding row) in the handler.

Comment: Just a note to other people who arrive at this question when looking for a solution to my problem: I set the blank row at the end of my DataGridView to ReadOnly since users are not allowed to create new rows but are allowed to change existing ones. I found that AcceptChanges clears the ReadOnly state of the blank row even though the changes relate to a completely different row! I have not discovered a solution except to reinstate the ReadOnly state after every call to AcceptChanges.